# Django Integrity Error- Unique Constraint Failed

Tags: python, django

Trying to create a simple launch page for my website to collect email addresses.  When the user goes to submit, it is providing the following error (traceback below)--Unique Constraint Failed---accounts.user.username.  I figured maybe this has to do with the email address entered overlapping with username, but as you can see in my accounts model--the username is created from the email.  (Note the entire User and User Profile models are not being utilized throughout my site yet, but just preparing for future usage).  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\PycharmProjects\dealmazing\dealmazing\views.py", line 15, in newsletter_signup
    instance.save()
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 74, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 708, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 736, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 820, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 859, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1039, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1060, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.username
```

my Accounts app model below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
    PermissionsMixin
)
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
import os


def avatar_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('avatars', 'user_{0}', '{1}').format(
        instance.user.id, filename)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username=None, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")

        if not username:
            username = email.split('@')[0]

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            username,
            password,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, default='')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_long_name(self):
        return "@{} ({})".format(self.username, self.email)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='', blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    avatar = models.ImageField('Avatar picture',
                               upload_to=avatar_upload_path,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @property
    def get_avatar_url(self):
        if self.avatar:
            return '/media/{}'.format(self.avatar)
        return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{}?s=128&d=identicon'.format(
            '94d093eda664addd6e450d7e9881bcad'
        )


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

and here's the view for my actual newsletter that is collecting email address. note i'm just temporarily redirecting to google for now as a test:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from newsletters.forms import NewsletterUserSignUpForm
from accounts.models import User


def newsletter_signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewsletterUserSignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            if User.objects.filter(email=instance.email).exists():
                print("Sorry this email already exists")
            else:
                instance.save()
                return redirect("http://www.google.com")

    else:
        form = NewsletterUserSignUpForm()

    template = "newsletters/sign_up.html"
    return render(request, template, {'form': form})
```

sign up html form looks like this:

```
  <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
      <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
         <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
          {{ form.email}}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up!</button>
           </div>
         </div>
      </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `User` model has a username field which requires `unique=True` which is the cause of your problem. Now you might be having a user having a username field as `''` which is default. Since you already have one user with this username you can't have another user with this field. You should check that user already exists in the db or not also you have to enter some username with a user don't use default with unique=True its a really bad design and always fails.

Comment: ok i think you are on the right trail here for sure.  there were two users in the database already--one a superuser with a username another user with the default '' username.  when i enter a username for this user with a blank username, the form works.  So, i deleted the default='' yet when i go to enter a new user email in the form, the problem keeps occuring.  Do i need to set the username to email in the view for the sign up  form?

Comment: You have to take a username field in form and check before saving that a user exists or not. Also don't make a username out of email if might turn out to be a username already exists in dB. Take username from user and check if it exists or not and if it does not exists then go ahead and create the user

Comment: my only issue here is that i'm just trying to create a temporary newsletter sign up form--where the only input would be email, so not collecting username from the user.

Comment: So remove the username field from your user model. Either way It looks redundant because of email.

Comment: got it--yeah ok i actually just removed the unique=True from username and that seems to do the trick...i want to just leave it for flexibility down the line.  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

since you are using `username = email.split('@')[0]` to get the username for the user. It is possible that two different email would give you same value for the `username`. For example `example@abc.com` and `example@def.com`. What you need to do is figure out some other algorithm to set the `username` or a good idea can be to user the `email` as username.

Comment: i don't think this is the problem--since i've tested it multiple times with lots of different emails and still getting same error for everything

Answer (score 0):

In your Accounts app model try this `user.save(using=self._db)` , this might help you